# Inkscape: Bitmap(s) disappearing when using perspective tool

Tags: inkscape, images, perspective

I have a gray image that I imported and embbeded into Inkscape.
I used Path->TraceToBitmap using gray options so I get different layers of bitmaps. I then group or ungroup them.

I then draw a polygon using the Bezier Pen starting by the bottom left corner with 4 nodes all connected. Select them then select the polygon with shift+click and use the perspective tool.

I get two different but similar results if they were ungrouped the first one disappear if they were grouped they all disappear.

I saw that there were a lot of tutorials/answers on Stackoverflow or elsewhere on using the perspective tool (for instance [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36539/add-perspective-to-bitmap-in-inkscape) or [this other one](http://goinkscape.com/using-perspective-for-3d-in-inkscape/) or [even this one](http://www.built-to-spec.com/blog/2011/01/02/quick-inkscape-tutorial-perspective-transforms/)) but I believe all the steps I took are correct.

Do you think there is a simple explanation to this strange behaviour ? Am I misunderstanding something still ?

**EDIT:** Apparently it moves the image to a 1pixel-1pixel aggregate which looks like a black sheet of paper folded multiple times. Any idea why it would do that ?
Is it my drawing of a rectangle like shape with the bezier pen ?

PS: I have no notions on graphical design so my question this might be silly but I couldn't figure out the answer by myself.

Comment: Perspective distorting a bitmap requires features that would mean need to recreate a bitmap. So its entirly possible that its just not allowed because it would go into a very gray area of how to handle this. And quite frankly all options that i can think of are bad in one way or another.

Comment: But they seem to be able to do it in the tutorial where the windows screen is moved into a computer so there is no reason it could not work for me. I am not that interested in the accuracy of the transformation I just want something that looks like it from afar.

Comment: It disappears too with simple text I am really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it !
When I drew the 4-angles shape with the bezier pen I used 4 strokes instead of one... 
I drew everey vertex by first clicking then dragging and then clicking twice. Starting from the end point of the previous vertex to draw the next one.

When I use two simple clicks instead of drawing I can make a connected shape and not 4 strokes that were not in fact connected (I did not know that) and thus produced this weird effect !

It drove me crazy at first !